# Atrix external storage functions return internal sdcard and not removable sdcard

Tags: android

I have a large (50 meg) download that I want to load to the sdcard if is mounted. If there is no sdcard, I download it to internal storage. I check for space available in both cases.

My code works great on the emulator and my Droid 2. My Atrix is a different story.

The Motorola Atrix has a built in sdcard. It can also have an external sdcard. The directories are mnt/sdcard and mnt/sdcard-ext. When checking external storage state, Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED is always returned. When using Environment.getExternalStorageState(), Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED is always returned. The standard external storage functions ignore the removable sdcard.

Is this unique to the Atrix? If not, do the other devices use sdcard-ext for the removable sdcard?

I really don't want to start coding for specific devices...

Comment: Ooops. change wording. getExternalStorage() always returns 'mnt/sdcard'.

Comment: I've decided that I'm going to let the download drop onto the built in sdcards. 50 meg is only 0.3% of 16 gig. That's what is built in on the SGS and Atrix, so it doesn't seem to be a problem to me. I'll leave this open for a couple of days to see if somebody has a better idea...

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's no standard Android API for accessing the truly external, removable, SD card.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android has a requirement that every device has an "shared" storage with a capacity of at least 1GB, that is mounted right out of the box, and it must be mounted to `/sdcard` (or at least symlinked from `/sdcard`). See section 7.6.2 of the Compatibility Definition Document, the most recent version of which is linked from [here](http://source.android.com/compatibility/overview.html).

So the manufacturer has the option of A. bundling a 1GB or higher SD card with each device, physically inside the device's SD card slot when it's in the box or B. partitioning the internal storage (or including a secondary internal storage) to provide at least 1GB "shared" storage, and mounting this at `/sdcard`. If there's a real SD card slot then this has to be mounted somewhere else.

Many manufacturers seem to choose B.

I guess the APIs that talk about "external storage" really mean "shared storage" in the CDD's terminology, and because of these requirements the "external" storage often isn't really external.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I know the SGS uses mnt/sdcard for its "internal" storage and mnt/sdcard-ext for its secondary card.